# Background-size:cover lagging

Tags: html, css

So I have this issue, on my website i have many sections with background-size:cover property on them, and that causes my website to lag like hell. Is there any solution to contain the 100% width of the picture on every device, but to get rid of website lagging? I've searched some other websites and found, the object-fit:cover on the img tags, but can't seem to implement that on my webpage. Also I compressed every image, so it takes less space. Any answer will be much of a help. Thanks in advance.

The [Website](http://www.thenamespace.com/NAMESPACEv2)

Comment: Share your website please, I dont think ´background-size: cover;´ causes the laggs

Comment: Website is still localhost, it does, I checked, when I remove them it scrolls smoothly

Comment: @Roman I would say **share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example** instead of a website or a codedump.

Comment: Well its hard to guess then, try to create a fiddle with the relevant code. Maybe your images are still way too big and take to much time to load. You could check the network in Browser Developer Tools.

Comment: Ok I uploaded it to my domain, www.thenamespace.com/NAMESPACEv2

Comment: Well, your website loaded instantly for me, maybe simply your connection is a bit low at this moment for some reasons?

Comment: Hmm, I tried on different places to connect, and different computers, but on every device it lags, when scrolling, it is not smooth as it should be, that is the main problem.

Comment: See my answer, your images are way too big

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your website loads fast for me (but I have a really fast connection). But nevertheless your images are way too big for your needs. For example the `box-2.jpg` has a `size: 3500 x 2333 px`. You should resize your images.

Just compressing the images wont help much here, because the size still remains and compressing too much is also bad because you always lose quality. For example the google speed insights always recommends to compress images to the maximum which is not the way to go.

But for you [google speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thenamespace.com%2FNAMESPACEv2%2F) is a good way to go to find other elememts which could be optimized.

Comment: Do you think, some other css approach would make a difference? Maybe not to use bg-size:cover , rather something else?

Comment: To be honest I dont think bg-size: cover; is the reason for this, but I never encountered such a problem, so I dont want to say somthing wrong here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to lower img size.